# For loop that only counts unique values

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, unique

My data frame consists of these columns: `A_NUMBER, B_NUMBER, DURATION`. I would like to count how many times `A_NUMBER` calls to a different `B_NUMBER` (to see how big their network is).

I first created a new column with all values set equal to 0.

```
df$CFU <- rep (0,nrow(df))
```

Next, I tried the following for loop:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(df)){ for (i in 1:nrow(unique(df$B_NUMBER))){ 
   if(df$A_NUMBER[i] == df$A_NUMBER[j]) {df$CFU[j] <- sum(df$CFU[j],1)  }}}
```

Then I get the following error:

> 'error in 1:nrow(unique(df$B_NUMBER)): argument of length 0.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Please give a reproducable example! Read [ask] and [mcve] ... then edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42806592/edit

Comment: The error is raised because you are asking for the number of rows of a vector (nrow(unique(df$B_NUMBER)). But apart from this, I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for an inverted index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood your question is that you are looking for is a list of unique B_NUMBERs for each A_NUMBER.

```
A_NUMBER = round(runif(100,0,10))
B_NUMBER = round(runif(100,0,10))
df = cbind(A_NUMBER, B_NUMBER)
aggregate(B_NUMBER ~ A_NUMBER, data=df, unique)

   A_NUMBER                   B_NUMBER
1         0                      10, 8
2         1           9, 3, 1, 7, 8, 0
3         2       7, 0, 6, 1, 9, 2, 10
4         3           7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5
5         4 7, 9, 3, 10, 4, 8, 1, 2, 5
6         5                 6, 5, 2, 8
7         6          4, 8, 9, 6, 10, 3
8         7     7, 3, 6, 0, 4, 1, 9, 8
9         8              7, 9, 8, 5, 2
10        9        8, 6, 2, 9, 0, 4, 1
11       10                          7
```

and then you can call the length of the vectors as

```
aggregate(B_NUMBER ~ A_NUMBER, data=df, function(x) length(unique(x))

   A_NUMBER B_NUMBER
1         0        2
2         1        6
3         2        7
4         3        6
5         4        9
6         5        4
7         6        6
8         7        8  
9         8        5
10        9        7
11       10        1
```

and check whether it was correct by

```
subset(df,A_NUMBER == 8)

       A_NUMBER B_NUMBER
 [1,]        8        7
 [2,]        8        9
 [3,]        8        7
 [4,]        8        8
 [5,]        8        5
 [6,]        8        7
 [7,]        8        2
 [8,]        8        2
 [9,]        8        8
```

Looks good, only 7s, 9s, 8s, 5s and 2s!

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide an example data, it is difficult to further examine what happened to your for loop. But based on the error message, it is clear that `1:nrow(unique(df$B_NUMBER))` is not working. The function `unique` returns a `vector`, which is one-dimensional. If you take this `vector` as your input to `nrow`, it will return `NULL`. It is possible that what you need is `length`, not `nrow`, in this case.

By the way, `df$CFU <- rep(0, nrow(df))` can be simplified to `df$CFU <- 0`